# How to format printed output so that each line of 6 strings is left aligned in Java?

Tags: java, string, formatting, alignment, printf

For example, let's say I have 6 words/strings on top of 6 other strings:

```
tiger   elephant  dog      fish  cat      jaguar
lion    human     manatee  cow   sphinx   cougar
```

I want it to line up as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, here's a simple example that might suit your needs:

```
String strings[][] = new String[][] {
     {"tiger", "elephant", "dog", "fish", "cat", "jaguar"},
     {"lion", "human", "manatee", "cow", "sphinx", "cougar"}
};

for (String[] line : strings) {
    System.out.printf("%-12s %-12s %-12s %-12s %-12s %-12s\n", 
        line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5]);
}
```

The output:

```
tiger        elephant     dog          fish         cat          jaguar      
lion         human        manatee      cow          sphinx       cougar
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your quick response  Kevin Anderson. This worked.

Comment: @KevinSerrano if that help you, you have to accept the answer instead you can read more [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: @YCF_L Oh ok, I'm new here. I clicked the check mark.